# POO - can't get length of iterables as a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, integer, tuples

My project: I trying to get two iterables and return one iterable.

Example:

```py
>>> iters = [i for i in range(5)], [i for i in range(10)]
>>> iters
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
>>> print([i for i in ranges(*iters, mtss=None)])
[(0, 0), (1, 1), ..., (8, None), (9, None)]
>>> print([i for i in ranges(*iters, maximum=False)])
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```

This is my code:

```py
from typing import Any, Iterable

class ranges(object):
    def __init__(self, __iter1: Iterable, __iter2: Iterable, /, *__iters: Iterable, maximum: bool=True, mtss=None) -> None:
        # mtss -> make them the same size
        lenghts= [len(__iter1), len(__iter2), *[len(i) for i in range(__iters)]]
        self.until: int = (max if maximum else min)(lenghts)
        self.iters: tuple[Iterable] = (__iter1, __iter2, *__iters)
        self.mtss: Any = mtss

    ...

print(ranges([i for i in range(2)], [i for i in range(3)]))
```

and err:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\areza\Desktop\delta\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(ranges([i for i in range(2)], [i for i in range(3)]))
  File "c:\Users\areza\Desktop\delta\__init__.py", line 6, in __init__
    lenghts= [len(__iter1), len(__iter2), *[len(i) for i in range(__iters)]]
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

if until == 3:

```py
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, None)]
```

I completed the code but I can't fix this line of code

Comment: ```*__iters``` is an tuple, so ```range(__iters)``` is invalid. Did you mean to write ```range(len(__iters))```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type annotations are not bying you anything, and are just making the code more difficult to understand...

And what's with the double underscore variable names..?!

In this line

```
lenghts= [len(__iter1), len(__iter2), *[len(i) for i in range(__iters)]]
```

the problem is

```
range(__iters)
```

since range requires an integer, and `__iters` is defined as a parameter tuple in this line:

```
def __init__(self, __iter1, __iter2, /, *__iters, maximum=True, mtss=None):
```

maybe you meant

```
range(len(__iters))
```

?

Comment: I did not mean exactly that, but thank you for saying I was wrong

Comment: To be fair, the Python error message here is not particularly helpful unless you already know why it is wrong ;-)